# Decay types before passing to std::result_of

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

As shown on this page http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async, one of the signature of `std::async` in C++14 has been changed from the C++11 version

```
template< class Function, class... Args>
std::future<typename std::result_of<Function(Args...)>::type>
    async( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

to

```
template< class Function, class... Args>
std::future<std::result_of_t<std::decay_t<Function>(std::decay_t<Args>...)>>
    async( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

The changes are the `std::decay_t`s (which remove references and cv-qualifiers and decay arrays/functions into pointers) applied on function and argument types before they are passed to `std::result_of`. I can't quite see why the decay is useful. For example, for a function type `Fn` (maybe a type alias of a closure class), passing `Fn`, `Fn&&`, `const Fn&` etc. all seem to yield the same result.

Can someone give me a concrete example where the decay is useful?

**UPDATE:** As an example, this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    auto fn = [](auto x) -> int { return x + 1; };

    using Fn = decltype(fn);
    using FnRef = Fn&;
    using FnCRef = const Fn&;
    using FnRRef = Fn&&;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << std::is_same<int, std::result_of_t<Fn(int)>>::value << '\n'
              << std::is_same<int, std::result_of_t<FnRef(int)>>::value << '\n'
              << std::is_same<int, std::result_of_t<FnCRef(int)>>::value << '\n'
              << std::is_same<int, std::result_of_t<FnRRef(int)>>::value << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

will print out four `true`s.

Comment: I think it has a meaning for reference to a function type.

Comment: @101010 Doesn't `decay` remove the reference qualification?

Comment: @101010 Please see my update.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The change is in response to [LWG 2021](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2021). The issue is that `async` (like `bind`, etc.) decay-copies all of its arguments and so if you didn't use `decay` in the return type you'd get the wrong return type when it comes to ref-qualifications and or rvalue-ness:

```
struct F {
    int operator()() &;
    char operator()() &&;

    int operator(int& ) const;
    char operator(int&& ) const;
};

auto future = std::async(F{}); // actually gives future<int>, but says
                               // it gives future<char>?
auto future2 = std::async(F{}, 1); // ditto
```

since all the arguments to async are MoveConstructed into its internal object, you will need to cleverly wrap them in order to actually achieve rvalue-ness of the arguments.

This makes sense - `async` *must* store its arguments somewhere, and if you pass in rvalues it must take ownership of them. If it holds onto rvalue references, the underlying object could get destroyed. But once it stores it as a `T`, it doesn't know where it came from a `T&` or a `T&&` - it just has a named lvalue argument at that point.

Comment: Ah. Things like these are why we truly love C++.

Comment: Note that the new version implies it `move`s the function and arguments out of its internal storage into the call expression, which is also the correct thing to do.

Comment: @Yakk The different semantics from `bind()` make it pretty confusing. I realize that thread/async are call-one and bind is potentially call-many, but it's still... confusing.

Comment: Which is why `bind` needs an rvalue overloaded `operator()` and an lvalue overloaded `operator()` to deal with this.  Similarly for lambdas: in an rvalue context, they should probably treat their local states as rvalues in their last use or something.  On the other hand, not sure how to make that syntax safe, non-surprising and efficient, so...  (non-surprising is the hard part!)

Comment: @Yakk What's the implication of this on the `std::decay`s? If the stored arguments are moved into the call expression, why use `std::decay` when deducing the result type?

Comment: @ZizhengTai Because they're moved in - as rvalues. If you don't `decay_t`, you'll be inspecting the return type as if they could be lvalues.